# Circleci buld should fail if css_lint returns errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, circleci, csslint

I have a rails application with CircleCI setup. I am using a `gem` called `css_lint` which returns the list of errors if the commit contains any CSS file error. Errors are returned but the build does not fail. I am also using `set -e` in the beginning. Below is my code. Please suggest how to fail my build in case of errors.

```
  - run:
      name: Run css_lint
      command: |
        set -e
        git diff -z --name-only --diff-filter=d origin/master...HEAD | grep -z -Z '.css$' | xargs -r -0 css_lint --errors=box-sizing,display-property-grouping,duplicate-properties,empty-rules,errors,known-properties
```

Comment: Why aren't you just running the linter against all of your files? Why only test the changed ones? Surely the whole thing runs in a second or two anyway?

Comment: @Jon because there are hundreds of files.

Comment: Are you certain css_lint exits with a non-zero code when it finds errors?